# Decorator function in python part2

Tags: python

```
def request(method="GET", path="", data=None):
    def wrapper(func):
        func.routed = True
        func.method = method
        func.path = path
        func.data = data
        return func
    return wrapper

def response(fmt="%s", contentType="text/plain"):
    def wrapper(func):
        func.format = fmt
        func.contentType = contentType
        return func
    return wrapper


 @request("GET", "%(channel)d/value")
    @response("%d")
    def digitalRead(self, channel):
    self.checkDigitalChannel(channel)
    return self.__digitalRead__(channel)
```

From last discussion,  we talked about
@A
@B
def func:

would become func=A()(B() func()) so from above, the @request and @response are wrapper so how would be new digitalRead function be like?

Answer (score 0):

The function would have the attributes given in the wrappers within the decorators added to it.

Comment: would be function becoming a GET HTTP Request?

Comment: I am looking for detailed example for better understanding.

Comment: let's go back to above example, digitalRead will have the attribute of  method=GET, path=x/value, routed=TRUE,  so what does it mean to all those?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. At least, not to anything else here. That doesn't mean that other parts of the framework in use won't look at those and build the route table appropriately. But your answer is not in this code.